# Draw a line in C# for metro app

Tags: microsoft-metro, drawing, line

I am trying to draw a line in a windows 8 app in c#. However, when I try to use

`Line myLine = new Line();` it does not work and tells me the namespace does not exist.

Using `LineGeometery myLine = new LineGeometery ();` does appear to create a new line and I can set the start and end points. However, as I cannot set the stroke, I really do not know if this is the correct approach. In fact, I am unsure on the difference between LineGeometery() and Line().

If anyone could help, that would be very appreciated.

```
<code>using System;

using System.Collections.Generic;

using System.IO;

using System.Linq;

using Windows.Foundation;

using Windows.Foundation.Collections;

using Windows.UI.Xaml;

using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;

using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives;

using Windows.UI.Xaml.Data;

using Windows.UI.Xaml.Input;

using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media;

using Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation;</code>
```

Answer (score 6):

Please add the following using in your application.
Windows.UI.Xaml.Shapes

Line class resides in the Windows.UI.Xaml.Shapes namespace.

Here's the part of code I used to add a line to a grid named LayoutRoot

```
Line line = new Line();
line.X1 = 10;
line.X2 = 200;
line.Y1 = 10;
line.Y2 = 200;
line.Stroke = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
LayoutRoot.Children.Add(line);
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the help! I added the Windows.UI.Xaml.Shapes and Line line = new Line(); worked perfectly. However, I cannot seem to get the 'Colors' namespace to register to color the line. I would have though I could implement 'using System.Drawing', but no go.

Comment: Is there another namespace I need to add? :)

Comment: Found it. Was missing 'using Windows.UI;'. Cheers. All working now!